# Population recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Was working on a population recursion problem a bit of a novice,....

I want to

1. Compute and plot the populations as a function of    using the recurrence relation  +1=  with initial condition  0 .

This is what i have so far..

```
A = np.array([[1,1/4,0],[0,3/4,1/2],[0,0,1/2]])
yk = np.array([[1000],[1000],[1000]])

       for i in range(100): 
            yk = A @ yk
            i += 1
            y1 = np.concatenate((yk))
            print(y1)
y1 = np.zeros((3,101), dtype = 'd') 


plt.plot(np.arange(101), y1.T, lw = 2.)
plt.legend(("White Walkers", 'Free Folk', "Night's watchmen"), fontsize = 16)
plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize = 16); plt.ylabel('Population', fontsize = 16)
```

Can seem to get it to plot y1

Comment: In the example you've given, y1 contains zeros. What are you trying to do with concatenate?

Comment: yes i am trying to concatenate and form a 101,3 matrix and the plot

Comment: The code as you've written won't even run because of  indentation problem; you should provide clean code that you've tested. You should not change the value of `i` iteration variable within the loop (i.e. `i+=1`). Please look at https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop. Code is executed from top to bottom, so after attempting to fill `y1`, you set `y1` to all zeros. Please see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html and carefully consider what you want.